# Was it a mistake to flag these answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, broken-link, declined-flags, not-an-answer

My *not an answer* flags for the below answers were declined "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

- [I am sorry I am kind of sleepy .. but you can read here to get an idea of your problem :) **[dead URL]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk/185946#185946)
- [This thread has a good discussion of this issue, near the bottom: **[dead URL]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176446/how-can-elements-be-added-to-a-wildcard-generic-collection/176469#176469)
- [Here's a post on Suns' site on how to do this... **[dead URL]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail/46680#46680)
- [There's a good explanation of how you can do this here: **[dead URL]** that can be extended to buttons of any shape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round/778265#778265)
- [The code here works great for my project. Check it out. **[dead URL]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java/2428490#2428490)
- [Two years ago I faced something similar, which made me remember of this discussion at Sun's Forum: **[dead URL]** Maybe this could be a starting point for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029430/java-integration-with-microsoft-help/2029463#2029463)

Was it a mistake to flag the above answers? Description for the flag I used says:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I think you should have stated explicitly that you were flagging these for the broken link. The one time I did that the flag was accepted and the answer deleted

Comment: Just curious, have you come up with some clever way to query for 'mostly link' answers and test them automatically? This was quite a series :)

Comment: @TimPost no automation sorry - this list is just a remainder of manual work done to `forums.sun.com` links: 1) I converted to `forums.oracle.com` where it was easy to do 2) ignored those where presence or absence of the link didn't make much difference to me 3) bookmarked for further investigation answers where I felt there was a chance to convert to `oracle` with some additional effort 4) flagged remaining answers which looked as good candidates to convert to comments or delete

Comment: @gnat Well, still good digging, nonetheless :)

Comment: Y'know... If you run out of flags, you could always replace the broken links with archive.org versions...

Comment: @Shog9 somehow, archive org wayback machine failed to recover Sun forums links I was testing it with. Feel free to test it eg with link mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035826/freetts-java-linux-workaround-for-line-unavailable-format-is)

Comment: Bummer, looks like the querystring throws it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many of these should have been removed regardless of the link being broken or not. But yes, flagging as 'other' and indicating a broken link would have helped quite a bit, if only to alert us that the 'answers' should not be converted to comments (or we'd just be turning a broken answer into a broken comment).

**Edit**

Wait, Jeff, I swear, we test *every single one* before converting it. Really, we do.

Comment: interesting. Answers are deleted, but flagging was incorrect anyway right? Sounds like flag description _should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether_ would better change to _let's play russian roulette with your flag weight_

Comment: @gnat What happened is another moderator looked at your second round. While personally, I would have validated the first round of flags and marked them as valid, they are a matter of interpretation. Use the 'other' feature in cases like this and `ctrl-v` a "not only does this answer depend on a link for it's context, the link it depends on is broken`. I don't have a way to go back and validate your previous flags, or I would, they were spot on. Sorry about that :(

Comment: @gnat In short, the first mod probably didn't realize the links were dead. It does make sense to add something like "Answer depends on a dead link" in the flag queue to reduce the work it takes to flag this type of thing. I'll propose that this coming week, and cite your post as an example.

Comment: I guess a related comment would be: Don't be afraid to change the flag type to "Other", and indicate what it is the question/answer is being flagged for - otherwise, it may not be clear why.

Comment: @TimPost: my last declined flag was a Very Low Quality because the link was 404. It'd be nice to know what you guys are looking for when we run across that.

Comment: @gnat VLQ is for something that you feel is so extremely problematic that it probably can't be salvaged by editing, or would require heroic editing in order to be something of any value to future visitors. The thing with flags is they are based on your perceptions when raising them, and then the mod's perceptions when investigating them. More often than not, if the mod can find _something_ less than trivial wrong with a post, the flag will be validated as helpful because it brought our attention to the post. The inconsistencies have improved a lot, and will continue to improve.

Comment: Tim, your comment above answers to @sixlettervariables not to me

Comment: @TimPost: I figured a 404 link-only answer was VLQ :) But I'd be happy with an "Answer is only a link, or a broken link".

Comment: @sixlettervariables It would be _nice_ to have a flag specific to that, just so we don't accidentally convert a broken link to a comment. Or, maybe the link could be checked for a `200` and say 'no' if `404`. I might raise this as a request sometime this week.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a mistake of flag all these answers, but you need to flag them in correct category. Some of the answers already selected as Answer for the question. All these may be related to the question but the link is broken now. As Yi Jinng's comment if you flagged as broken link all these may accepted by the moderators.